# how to put the Snap Daemon service as the last service to start?

Tags: snap, systemd

I have faced some problems with snap, at the beginning of the system, when starting the service, there are several mounting errors, due to the fact of placing the .snap files on a hard disk partition, and on my main partition, root, I have ssd, but I want it to work this way. (just preciosity on my part, in trying to increase the life of the ssd, including some caches I also direct to the hard disk).

In short, I need to put the snap service and other snap, in the final, and I don't know if that would also solve, because when I stop the service and start again, after the system is loaded, it seems to work normally. So that's why, my idea of putting it up in the end.

What do you think of that, or do you have another idea?

---

Ahh !!! I remembered that the problem is with the mount points, when starting the system, all of them are unable to mount

> command> systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
>
> UNIT FILE                                    STATE   VENDOR PRESET
> snap-android\x2dstudio-99.mount              enabled enabled
> snap-chromium\x2dffmpeg-17.mount             enabled enabled
> snap-code\x2dinsiders-633.mount              enabled enabled
> snap-code\x2dinsiders-634.mount              enabled enabled
> snap-core-10583.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-core-10823.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-core18-1944.mount                       enabled enabled
> snap-core18-1988.mount                       enabled enabled
> snap-core20-875.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-core20-904.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-flutter-47.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-flutter-48.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-freemind-4.mount                        enabled enabled
> snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount      enabled enabled
> snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount      enabled enabled
> snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1513.mount      enabled enabled
> snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount      enabled enabled
> snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dcommunity-270.mount enabled enabled
> snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dcommunity-273.mount enabled enabled
> snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-266.mount  enabled enabled
> snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-269.mount  enabled enabled
> snap-netbeans-35.mount                       enabled enabled
> snap-netbeans-41.mount                       enabled enabled
> snap-ngrok-29.mount                          enabled enabled
> snap-notekit-9.mount                         enabled enabled
> snap-opera-100.mount                         enabled enabled
> snap-phpstorm-197.mount                      enabled enabled
> snap-phpstorm-200.mount                      enabled enabled
> snap-postman-131.mount                       enabled enabled
> snap-postman-132.mount                       enabled enabled
> snap-powershell-149.mount                    enabled enabled
> snap-powershell-154.mount                    enabled enabled
> snap-pycharm\x2deducational-34.mount         enabled enabled
> snap-pycharm\x2deducational-35.mount         enabled enabled
> snap-rider-141.mount                         enabled enabled
> snap-rider-145.mount                         enabled enabled
> snap-speedy\x2dduplicate\x2dfinder-28.mount  enabled enabled
> snap-webstorm-187.mount                      enabled enabled
> snap-webstorm-189.mount                      enabled enabled

My dmesg

```
    3.442499] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/android-studio_100.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.444507] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_17.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.449011] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/code-insiders_654.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.451956] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/code-insiders_655.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.454076] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_10823.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.457199] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_10859.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.459780] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1944.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.461674] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1988.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.464448] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_875.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.466716] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_904.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.470740] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/flutter_50.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.473131] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/flutter_56.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.475676] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/freemind_4.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.478013] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_128.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.479734] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_145.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.483103] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1513.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.484713] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1514.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.488181] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/intellij-idea-community_273.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.490440] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/intellij-idea-community_286.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.492518] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/intellij-idea-ultimate_269.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.495582] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/intellij-idea-ultimate_282.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.497450] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/netbeans_41.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.500580] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/netbeans_45.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.503074] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/ngrok_29.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.505055] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/notekit_9.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.508920] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/opera_100.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.511047] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/phpstorm_197.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.514017] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/phpstorm_200.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.516575] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_132.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.518914] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/postman_133.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.521315] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/powershell_158.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.523103] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/powershell_160.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.526926] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-educational_35.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.528944] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-educational_36.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.532341] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/rider_145.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.535405] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/rider_161.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.538108] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/speedy-duplicate-finder_28.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.541525] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/webstorm_187.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    3.544166] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/webstorm_189.snap: Can't open blockdev
```

Comment: This is certainly an interesting idea. Unfortunately, `snapd` is not a service that we can start, stop, enable, or disable like other `systemd` services. It's unlikely that you'll be able to easily move its startup to the end of a boot sequence 

Comment: The snapd .service file indicates that snapd is required by multi-user.target, one of the final targets in the boot sequence. In other words, it's *already* near the end.